# How to fix: "stream ended unexpectedly" when i tried to upload file in node js using adonis framework

Tags: javascript, node.js, adonis.js

I'm trying to upload file to a local folder, and I used the code in the  official website and i just copied it like literally but it always show "stream ended unexpectedly" when I tried to upload.

I tried console.log in the function in the route, but it didn't work or didn't responds. So i think the problem is when I try to send the file to the router, but i don't know what exactly the problem and how to fix it. Please help me. Sorry if my English is bad.

```
<form method="POST" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" name="profile_pic">

 <button type="submit"> Submit </button>

</form>



const Helpers = use('Helpers')

Route.post('/upload', async ({ request }) => {
console.log("hai")
const profilePic = request.file('profile_pic', {
  types: ['image'],
  size: '2mb'
})

await profilePic.move(Helpers.tmpPath('uploads'), {
  name: 'custom-name.jpg'
})

if (!profilePic.moved()) {
  return profilePic.error()
}
return 'File moved'
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

already fixed, it's because of the adonis framework that I had is not the usual adonis (with frontend), the adonis that i'm using is for API only.

that's why, installing a new adonis project the usual way (not API only) fixed it.

Comment: I don'T understand what that mean's or what I have to do to fix it. in my case it works locally, but not when it'S deployed on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It likely has to do with the 
"size" control variable. Try this code instead...

```
// getting the image
const image = request.file('image', {
    maxSize: '20mb',
    allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'png', 'jpeg']
    })

// move image to uploads folder
await image.move(Helpers.tmpPath('uploads'), {
    name: image_name,
    overwrite: false
})

if (!image.moved()) {
    return image.error()
}
```

Comment: I tried using your code, it's still "stream ended unexpectedly".

As i previously said, i think the problem is from the "view" where i put the HTML, the file can't go to the router / the function. I know this because i tried console.log() in the top of the function and it won't run the console.log()